# HiFiBerry Board compatibility

Tags: audio, server, media, hifiberry

I want to create a music server/player with the Pi as the heart.  Will the HiFiBerry Amp+ work in conjunction with their DAC board? The reason for this thought is I'd like the music bod to operate as a stand alone machine but have the capability to be patched into a larger stereo with the on-board connections, if I felt so inclined. I understand an expansion board or jumpers can facilitate the physical connections but do the boards play nice in the sandbox together?

I'd also appreciate any thoughts or reviews on these boards as I'm hoping to achieve a truly beautiful sound with my project.

Comment: I would add that you may want to ask on the berrybot site regarding the compatability of HiFiBerry and their DAC board.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here but you do figure this out, please come back and leave your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that those boards will not play nice in the sandbox together - at least not as supplied and without further hacks.

The [Amp+](https://www.hifiberry.com/ampplus/) and the [DAC+ board](https://www.hifiberry.com/dacplus/) share the following pins (see here  [GPIO usage](https://www.hifiberry.com/guides/gpio-usage-of-the-hifiberry-products/)):

- GPIO 2 and 3 for configuration
- GPIO 28 through 31 for the sound interface

For pins 28..31 they also explicitely state that:

> You can’t use them for any other purpose.

In my book this means that the two will not be able to be operated on one Pi.

Furthermore it is noteworthy that there are no stacked HATs - and the newer HiFiBerry boards share the Foundations EEPROM based configuration approach. Per [Raspberry Pi Blog](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-hats/):

> Stackable HATs featured in the specification discussion – but eventually it was thrown out due to the large increase in complexity of autoconfig and potential for user error.

So at any given time only one HAT could be connected, have its EEPROM read out, and made its information available at the device tree.

---

The [DAC](https://www.hifiberry.com/dac) (not DAC+) on the other hand does not use any of the GPIO pins (neither EEPROM nor DAC-data) but the onboard sound connector P5. However it only works with the older Raspberry Pi models A and B - but then again the Amp+ is not going to be compatible with those.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not using any HiFiBerry boards as of now, so this answer is based on the available documentation only.</sup>

Comment: wonderful! thank-you so much for your information!! I'm still in the research portion of my project, starting to lean maybe towards gutting a small amplifier, powering it independently and using the RCA out from the DAC+, from what I understand it's sound quality is tops and closer to my goal!

Comment: Jake, that should not prevent you from sharing your experience or any feedback you might get someplace else, just as @goldilocks suggested.