# Simple circuit for audio amplifier

Tags: audio

I'm trying to add a speaker to an RPi project, and from what I've read, the RPi's built-in headphone jack is nearly useless for driving even tiny headphone speakers.

What is a good audio amplifier to use to power a fairly small 8ohm 0.5W speaker from the RPi's headphone jack? Can it be something as simple as a [mosfet switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11L3V.gif), with the gate connected to the headphone jack's signal pin? Or do I need to use something more sophisticated like the circuit outlined [here](http://marktmarshall.com/projects/previous-projects/simple-1w-5v-amplifier/)?

I don't have a lot of room in my project, so I can't use a generic off-the-shelf powered speaker. I can fabricate simple circuits myself, but I don't have a lot of resources or time to debug complex circuits, so I need something super simple.

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39530/hifiberry-board-compatibility

Comment: ... and if you're looking into circuit design I'd suggest to take it to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, being *extremely* lazy, if it's for a one-off project I'd just buy one. Adafruit do a few nice (cheap) little amplifier boards:

[Adafruit Mono 2.5W Class D Audio Amplifier - PAM8302](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2130)

[Stereo 3.7W Class D Audio Amplifier - MAX98306](https://www.adafruit.com/products/987)

Comment: 5 for a £ at http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/141663242851

Comment: I've had one or two bad experiences with cheap as chips class D audio boards in the past, but at that price those are certainly worth a punt.